# Prevent observer to retain live-data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, observers

How to prevent observer to retain live-data in Android fragments?

First time open the fragment and called the API in interface method. But After once  live data observer called multiple times in Fragment without API call when I switch the fragments. SO i need to know how to stop observer without API call.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.